# Нахождение числа в таблице

Tags: html, javascript

Есть исходный код:
http://jsfiddle.net/nhbv4wvp/

Что нужно сделать, чтобы вместо того, чтобы создавались элементы <p> и <b>, нужное число в таблице становилось красным?

Comment: Это же дубль вопроса http://hashcode.ru/questions/387966/ 
Только сейчас заметил : (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно пробегаясь по всем `<td>` смотреть, есть ли значение в массиве, и если есть, добавлять этой ячейке красный класс. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nhbv4wvp/6/).

Comment: А как сделать по этому принципу: В таблице например три числа (4 4 3), Число 4 - зелёное, число 3 - красное. Как чтобы они в одной <td> стали разных цветов? Все четвёрки должны стать зелёными, а тройки красными.

Comment: в одной ячейке – обернуть каждое в свой `<span>`

Answer (score 0):

если бы вы использовали jquery, я бы вам быстро написал), но а так вы просто достаете значения из каждой ячейки таблицы и проверяете на соответствие, тоясть в for, добавляете ещё один for и уже в нем проверяете!